# How to tell if an image is 90% black?

Tags: image, algorithm, fuzzy-comparison

I have never done image processing before.

I now need to go through many jpeg images from a camera to discard those very dark (almost black) images.

Are there free libraries (.NET) that I can use?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/) is a great image processing library. Specifically the `Aforge.Imaging` assembly.
You could try to apply a threshold filter, and use an area or blob operator and do your comparisons from there.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the Image Processing Lab from Aforge. If I want to keep things simple, will it work if I simply take the YMeanWB or YMedianWB values of an image (I see these under Image Statistics) and cut off at a certain threshold?

Comment: @OldGeezer Depends entirely on your criteria of "mostly black". Some images might be black but overexposed in a small area, which might cause your YMedian values to drift. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing.  I came up with this solution to flag mostly black images.  It works like a charm.  You could enhance it to delete or move the file.

```cs
// set limit
const double limit = 90;

foreach (var img in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"E:\", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    // load image
    var sourceImage = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(img);

    // format image
    var filteredImage = AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone(sourceImage);

    // free source image
    sourceImage.Dispose();

    // get grayscale image
    filteredImage = Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.RMY.Apply(filteredImage);

    // apply threshold filter
    new Threshold().ApplyInPlace(filteredImage);

    // gather statistics
    var stat = new ImageStatistics(filteredImage);
    var percentBlack = (1 - stat.PixelsCountWithoutBlack / (double)stat.PixelsCount) * 100;

    if (percentBlack >= limit)
        Console.WriteLine(img + " (" + Math.Round(percentBlack, 2) + "% Black)");

    filteredImage.Dispose();
}

Console.WriteLine("Done.");
Console.ReadLine();
```